# Unresolved standard C++ features

Tags: c++, linker

This might be a noob question But i searched everywhere and the only answer i find is the include the standard lib, which isnt my issue.

Im writing a program that needs to make a http request to an API, without this class the program compiles fine even using std library but when init the httpclient and compiling the linker says these errors;

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn  Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\Pogobot.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___std_exception_copy    Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___std_exception_copy    Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\LIBCMT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___std_exception_destroy Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol ___std_exception_destroy Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\LIBCMT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CxxThrowException@8    Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CxxThrowException@8    Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\LIBCMT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __callnewh   Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\LIBCMT.lib(new_scalar.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _malloc  Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\LIBCMT.lib(new_scalar.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _free    Pogobot C:\Visual Studio 2017\projects\Pogobot\Pogobot\LIBCMT.lib(delete_scalar.obj)    1
```

my http class

```
#pragma once
#ifndef HTTP_CLIENT_H_
#define HTTP_CLIENT_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

#define  _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

class HttpClient {
private:
    unordered_map<string, string> params;
    string hostName;
    string requestPath;
    int method = 2;
    thread *requestThread;
public:
    static const int POST = 1, GET = 2;

    void sendAsync(string host, function<void(string, string)> onResponse) {
        requestThread = new thread(&HttpClient::_send, this, host, onResponse);
    }

    void sendSync(string host, function<void(string, string)> onResponse) {
        return _send(host, onResponse);
    }

    void waitForResult() {
        requestThread->join();
    }

    void setParam(string key, string val) {
        params[key] = val;
    }

    void setMethod(int method) {
        this->method = method;
    }

    void setPath(string path) {
        this->requestPath = path;
    }

    void _send(string host, function<void(string, string)> onResponse) {
        hostName = host;
        WSADATA wsa;
        if (WSAStartup(514, &wsa) != 0) {
            return;
        }
        struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
        SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        if (getaddrinfo(host.c_str(), "80", &hints, &result) != 0) {
            return;
        }
        for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {
            ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
            if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                WSACleanup();
                return;
            }
            if (connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
                continue;
            } else {
                string request;
                if (method == HttpClient::GET) {
                    request += "GET ";
                    request += requestPath;
                    request += '?';
                    for (auto r : params) {
                        request += r.first;
                        request += "=";
                        request += r.second;
                    }
                    request += " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                    request += "Host: ";
                    request += hostName;
                    request += "\r\n\r\n";
                }
                else if (method == HttpClient::POST) {
                    request += "POST ";
                    request += requestPath;
                    request += " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
                    string paramsString;
                    for (auto r : params) {
                        if (paramsString.size()) paramsString += '&';
                        paramsString += r.first;
                        paramsString += "=";
                        paramsString += r.second;
                    }
                    request += "Host: ";
                    request += hostName;
                    request += "\r\n";
                    request += "Content-Length: ";
                    request += to_string(paramsString.size());
                    request += "\r\n";
                    request += paramsString;
                    request += "\r\n";
                } else {
                    return;
                }
                ::send(ConnectSocket, request.c_str(), request.size(), 0);
                char *header = new char[4096];
                int headerLen = ::recv(ConnectSocket, header, 4096, 0);
                header[headerLen] = 0;
                string headerString(header);
                unsigned contentLenPos = headerString.find("Content-Length:");
                if (contentLenPos == string::npos) {
                    return;
                }
                unsigned contentLenEndPos = headerString.find('\n', contentLenPos);
                string ln = headerString.substr(contentLenPos + 15, contentLenEndPos - contentLenPos - 15);
                int blen;
                if (!(ln[0] == '"' || (ln[0] < 58 && ln[0]>47))) {
                    blen = 4096;
                } else { 
                    blen = stoi(ln);
                }
                char *body = new char[blen + 1];
                int bodyLen = ::recv(ConnectSocket, body, blen, 0);
                body[bodyLen] = 0;
                onResponse(header, body);
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

the rest of my code works, but when trying to make a http request the linker says basic C features are unresolved and I cant figure out why. It confuse me why such functions like free() and memcpy() arent resolved.

edit 1: i set the verbose linker topo see where its searching, this is the output.

```
1>Searching libraries
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\ws2_32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\user32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\winspool.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\shell32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\ole32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\uuid.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\lib\x86\libcpmt.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\lib\x86\LIBCMT.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\lib\x86\OLDNAMES.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\ws2_32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\user32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\winspool.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\shell32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\ole32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\uuid.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib\odbccp32.lib:
1>    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\lib\x86\libcpmt.lib:
```

Comment: That seems an odd place for libcmt.lib to be located (a project subdirectory called Pogobot), especially since you're using Visual Studio and the default library path should already provide that library. is this project intentionally using some special build of the C++ standard runtime?

Comment: no, no special c++, just standard vs2017 install. but that is the correct project directory. and for reference there are no libs in the project directory

Comment: You missed my point. LIBCMT.LIB is provided from MS and in the VC library folder already. It's the statid multi-threaded basic runtime. The same is true for a variety of libs. Whatever *that* library is, it  probably isn't the correct one. You should likely be using the toolchain's library and not the one under Pogobot.

Comment: Update. Figured it out. Because I set the entry point to something different. that's what was causing the linker errors. BUT only when I use the http class. feels like it shouldnt happen. But it does :/